# SQLite.swift-master Xcode 8.2.1 Swift 3.0.2

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite

I have imported SQLite.swift-master/sources/sqlite manually in my project.

Linked libsqlite3.0.tbd in Build Phase

Changed in Swift Compiler - General the Objective-C Bridging Header to $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)/SQLite.h

Xcode still give me compile error at "import SQLite"

Comment: The suspense is killing me. What compile error does it give you?

Comment: That SQLite don't exist

Comment: You don't want to change the name of the objective-c bridging header. The bridging header should be a header you own, not one from another project. Inside the bridging header, you want to import any Objective-C headers that you want to be able to call from Swift code in your project. SQLite should be building its own framework that you import.

Comment: Did you follow the Manual instructions on the README? https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/README.md